# how to make ajax calls continuously for 5 seconds once

Tags: jquery, ajax, settimeout

How to make ajax calls continuously for 5 seconds once.

I have used `setTimeout` like below,

```
setTimeout(function()
{
    someFn();
}, 200);
```

But it use more db connection. Can anyone tell me an effective way to call a function continuously for 5 seconds once.

Function that i use inside setTimeout or setInterval will be used to update values to database.hence this will increase db connections. and result in lost db connection error.so i need something that will not increase db connections

i am using below code

```
push_notification('<?php echo $user_details1[0]['id']; ?>');

setInterval(function() 
{
    push_notification('<?php echo $user_details1[0]['id']; ?>');

}, 10000);


function push_notification(driver_id)
{

    var dataS = "&type=1&driver_id="+driver_id;
    var SrcPath = "<?php echo URL_BASE; ?>";
    var response;

    $.ajax
    ({          
        type: "POST",
        url: SrcPath+"driver/adminpushnotification/1", 
        data: dataS, 
        cache: false, 
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(response) 
        {   
            //some Functionality
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? What do you want to achieve? Do you want to make an ajax request every 200 ms but only if no previous request is pending? And then stop sending after 5 seconds?

Answer (score 1):

This will execute `fn` every `interval` milliseconds, and after `duration` milliseconds it will stop.

```
var duration = 5000,
    interval = 200,
    intervalTimer;

intervalTimer = setInterval(function() {
    fn();
}, interval);

setTimeout(function() {
    clearInterval(intervalTimer);
}, duration);
```

#### Update

However, if you're making ajax requests within the interval callback, and want to prevent a new request from being made while a previous request is still pending (as I'm now interpreting your question), you can check the status of the previous request before making a new one. Providing you're using jQuery, it could look something like this:

```
var duration = 5000,
    interval = 200,
    xhrPending = false,
    intervalTimer;

intervalTimer = setInterval(function() {
    if (xhrPending) return;

    $.ajax(...).done(function() {
        xhrPending = false;
    });

    xhrPending = true;
}, interval);

setTimeout(function() {
    clearInterval(intervalTimer);
}, duration);
```

Comment: This solution is more elegant that mine.

Comment: Op is looking for doing some ajax requests, your code is calling a request every 200ms without waiting for any previous request to complete, this isn't a great thing. This would be better to recall next request from compltete callback of previous one, eventually without or with delaying it

Comment: I interpreted this as the core of the question: "Can anyone tell me an effective way to call a function continuously for 5 seconds once."

Comment: @HannesJohansson Ya but OP is clearly talking about making ajax requests, otherwise your solution would be great for synchronous operations

Comment: I updated the answer according to the best understanding of the whole question as I can come up with.

Answer (score 0):

```
This will execute for every 3 seconds.

  <button onclick="setInterval(function(){alert('Hello')},3000);">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: Function that i use inside setTimeout or setInterval will be used to update values to database.hence this will increase db connections. and result in lost db cinnection error.so i need something that will not increase db connections.

Answer (score 0):

A hacky way would be to call it every 200 ms 25 times, resulting in stopping after 5 seconds (25 calls).

This will call the function ajaxCall() 25 times before clearing the interval after 5 seconds.

```
var ajaxInterval = setInterval(function(){AjaxTimer()},200);
var counter = 1;

function AjaxTimer()
{
  if(counter > 25) {
    clearInterval(ajaxInterval );
  } else {
    ajaxCall();
    counter++;
  }
}
```