# Call python function with ajax and flask continously

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask

I need to call flask function in python with ajax continously. To that I have following script in html file.

```
<script  >
 var ajaxFUN = function () {
   $.ajax({
     url: '/toAjax',
     dataType: 'json',
     success: function (data) {
       console.log('get info');
       $('#data').html(data['data']);
     }
   });
 }
 setTimeout(ajaxFUN, 1);
</script>
```

And here is the python code

```
@app.route('/toAjax')
def ajaxTo():

    print("AJAX WAS HERE")
    data= reader.getToAjax()

    info = {
        "data": data

    }
    return jsonify(info)
```

I need to call /toAjax header route in the python continously without hitting any button or any kind of method.

But that implementation prints only once AJAX WAS HERE. Where is the missing  part ? How can I fix it ?

Here is the similiar questions which I have looked:
[setTimeout() and setting parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5169020/settimeout-and-setting-parameters)
[how to make ajax calls continuously for 5 seconds once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31759545/how-to-make-ajax-calls-continuously-for-5-seconds-once)

Comment: `setTimeout(ajaxFUN, 1);` calls it once - and I wouldn't use setInterval with an interval of 1, that would be ridiculous - hint: add `ajaxFUN()` after the line `$('#data').html(data['data']);` to call the function again once the previous request is done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setTimeout` triggers exactly once (unless cancelled)

you could use `setInterval`, but that's likely to flood your server at the rate you've used for `setTimeout`

I would recommend the following

```
 var ajaxFUN = function () {
   $.ajax({
     url: '/toAjax',
     dataType: 'json',
     success: function (data) {
       console.log('get info');
       $('#data').html(data['data']);
       ajaxFUN(); // this calls the function again
     }
   });
 }
 ajaxFUN();
```

In case you're worried, there's no "recursion", since `ajaxFUN()` is being called in an asynchronous callback

Comment: Thank  you very much it worked. But I have question, using this kind of  code is it appropriate for application ?

Comment: depends on what you mean by "this kind of code" - do you mean "code that does what you want"?

Comment: Yes exactly code that does what I want, because I am new in this area, and stackoverflow is only my guidleline. Thanks for your contribution. Therefore I am not sure whether it is ok or not

Comment: @GhostDede - well, the only reason this may not be "appropriate" is if the server can't handle the constant requests